# BeanCreationException : Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring-bean

I have 2 classes in 2 different projects, and I have some difficulties to autowire a field.

In project pack, I have this Computation class :

```
package fr.aaa;

@Component
public class Computation {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("curveDAO")
    CurveAccess curveDAO;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:applicationContext.xml");
    }
}
```

In project db, I have this CurveAccess interface :

```
package com.bbb

public interface CurveAccess {
    // some methods
}
```

implemented by a CurveDAO class :

```
package com.bbb.impl

@Repository("curveDAO")
@Transactional("cvaTxManager")
public class CurveDAO implements CurveAccess {
    // some methods
}
```

My applicationContext.xml file from pack project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">  

<import resource="classpath:spring/persistence.xml"/>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="fr.aaa.*, com.bbb.*"/> 

<util:properties id="jdbcProps" location="jdbc.properties" />   

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
         <value>classpath:configuration.properties</value>
         <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When running, I have this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Computation': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.bbb.CurveAccess fr.aaa.Computation.curveDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.bbb.CurveAccess] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=curveDAO)}
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Where is your implementation of `CurveAccess` ?

Comment: Why are you mixing annotations and xml? What a nightmare.

Comment: Try not use wildcard and put com.bbb and com.bbb.impl inside base-package separately.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code works perfectly fine:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So21481801Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public interface CurveAccess {
        String hello();
    }

    @Repository("curveDAO")
    public class CurveDAO implements CurveAccess {
        @Override
        public String hello() {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }

    @Repository("curveDAOWorld")
    public class CurveDAOWorld implements CurveAccess {
        @Override
        public String hello() {
            return "World";
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("curveDAO")
    CurveAccess curveDAO;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("curveDAOWorld")
    CurveAccess curveDAOWorld;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println(curveDAO.hello());
        System.out.println(curveDAOWorld.hello());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So21481801Application.class, args);
        context.close();
    }

}
```

Probably you have some problem on how you are using the `component-scan` configuration on XML and the Java annotations. Mix them is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need a class that implements `CurveAccess` interface

```
@Component
public class CurveAccessImpl implements CurveAccess {
    //methods
}
```

Also remove `Qualifier` from `curveDao` in `Computation` bean since there is no such bean with id `curveDao`.

```
@Autowired
CurveAccess curveDAO;
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot the implementation in the question (but not in the code !). I removed the Qualifier annotation, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Is it defined as bean? `@Component` or in xml? In some way, spring can't find it.